# Firebase combined analytics and error reporting in free and paid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, android-productflavors, firebase-crash-reporting

We have a free and paid version of our application that share 99% of the same code.  However because we're using product flavors the apps are built with a different applicationId.

My understanding is that Firebase can easily group multiple applications into the same profile.  When we configure the applications to be grouped together in Firebase, do we see our analytics and error reporting as one combined dashboard?

I want to be able to see crash reporting and analytics aggregated across both product flavors.  I want to avoid having separate dashboards to check for each app (even a dropdown menu is not desirable).

Can anyone confirm Firebase will aggregate analytics and error reporting into a single dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

Analytics uses Google App ID instead of your application ID. It doesn't group your apps into the same dashboard based on your application ID automatically. If you would like both direct to the same dashboard, you can use the same Google App ID ("google_app_id" inside google-service.json). Note that it may be confusing if you have the same events in 2 apps as they will be grouped together. For example, let's say you have both in app purchase events on both apps, the life time value will be the total of both apps.

Comment: Thanks.  That's the distinction I remember.  The Google App ID vs. application id.  Do you know of any marketing material from Google that highlights this difference?

Comment: I don't think there is an official documentation that states this difference but from my own experience, that's what it is.